# Page load actions in angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am from jquery background working on angular application currently. I want to include some code which we did on page load in jquery to store arrays in sessionobject.
e.g.

```
  $(document).ready(function(e) {
    Storage.prototype.setObj = function(key, obj) {
    return this.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(obj))
}
Storage.prototype.getObj = function(key) {
    return JSON.parse(this.getItem(key))
}
});
```

How can I do same in my angular application. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use the `config` function of your main module, e.g. `var app = angular.module("main",[...]); app.config(function() { /*HERE*/ });`

Comment: Why does this have to run on the DOMReady event at all? Would this not work if you just did `Storage.prototype…` in JavaScript outside any callback?

Comment: Hi Nikos, I tried config function but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using init function. In the html file add the following code -

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-init="init()">
    </div>
</div>
```

Then in main.js file, do the following -

```
var app=angular.module("MyApp",[])
app.controller("myCtrl",function($scope){
$scope.init(function () {
    // Add your code here
    })
})
```

Comment: Or they can make a directive for it, or a service or a separate module...but there's absolutely no point ! :)